# Append data to the end of a file in python

Tags: python, function, file, append

I am trying to append data to a file. Each line gets written inside a function. Below is a sample code based on my actual code:

```
a = 0

def data():
    global a
    a = int(raw_input('Enter value for a\n>'))
    write()

def write():
    f = open('path\\to\\file.txt', "a")
    f.write('%s\n' % a)
    f.close
    proceed()

def proceed():
    should = raw_input('Please press enter to continue or type in 0 to stop\n>')
    if should == '0':
        return
    else:
        data()

data()
```

When I run the code and give, for example, `1, 2 and 3` as values for a, this is how it gets written to the file:

```
3
2
1
```

But I want it to be written to the file this way:

```
1
2
3
```

What would be the right way to do that? How do I append a new line at the end of a file every time I run the `write` function?

Comment: `f.close` doesn't close the file! and using globals to pass data is not recommended. Use parameters. And finally, I really don't see why you get this output. append mode cannot revert the order of the lines, it makes no sense.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Thanks a lot. Got it to work.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre That's what I too didn't understand. Even if the file wasn't closed shouldn't append always write data to the end of the file?

Answer (score 2):

Your program structure gives rise to a possibly very deep recursion (problem). Because in data(), you call write(), and in write() you call proceed(), and in proceed() you call data() again. Try to avoid this kind of structure. The following code avoids this problem, and is shorter:

```
def data():
    while True:
        a = int(raw_input('Enter value for a\n>'))
        f.write(str(a) + '\n')

        should = raw_input('Please press enter to continue or type in 0 to stop\n>')
        if should == 0:
            break


f = open('path\\to\\file.txt', "a")
data()
f.close()
```

Comment: The sample code I provided is just to show the structure of my actual code. For just getting an input and writing it to a file your code works excellently. But in my original code I have quite a few functions and for each successive function to run properly the preceding one should run without any error. That's why I have structured my code this way. However, can you possibly explain why appending behaves the way it does when the file wasn't closed properly? Thank you.

Comment: The structure of your actual code gives rise to possible recursion errors. This means you can call data() only so many times before the interpreter will throw an error as it calls a function that calls a funtion that calls data() again. The calls in this chain have to be tracked by the interpreter, and there is only so much storage space to do so. So finally, you are going to run out of stack space - welcome to Stackoverflow :) I don't know why the values are written top-down when you don't close your file properly. I suppose it might be a file buffer not flushed before the close() statement.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Ukimiku. I'll try to restructure my program to avoid recursion errors :)

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to implement your demands has been given by @Ukimiku.
As for why your code behaves like that, my opinion is here.
In fact, open a file with `open('path','a')` will move the file pointer to the end of the file you open so that when you use `write()`, you append something.

```
f = open('path\\to\\file.txt', "a")
print f.tell() #get the position of current file pointer
f.write('%s\n' % a)
```

Add `print f.tell()` after you open file.txt. You will find every time you open it, the pointer position is always 0, which indicates that your `write()` operation insert those numbers at the beginning of that file. This happened because of no closing. Those changes happen in memory and haven't been written to disk yet.

Comment: Thanks a lot for explaining that :)